# Increment a global variable - can EVM nodes overwrite each other?

Tags: solidity

I have the following contract:

```
contract Contract{
  address minter;
  uint gid;

  //...

  //constructor
  function Contract(){
    minter=msg.sender;
    gid=0;
  }
  function kill(){
    if (msg.sender == minter){
      suicide(minter);
    }
  }

  function createAgreement(string name){
      //blah, blah
      //...

      gid++;   //what happens here?!
  }
```

What happens if 100 users all call `createAgreement(...)` at the same time (i.e. on the same `eth.blockNumber`)? Do EVM nodes compete with each other?

I need `gid` to be unique for each of these 100 users!

Will `gid` be unique? Or do I need to do something different?

Comment: I did some testing and it appears that gid is being incremented correctly?! Can someone more knowledgeable on blockchains please explain this to me? I guess this is the wonder of blockchain, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All comptutations that end up on the block chain are done by the lucky miner that mines a block. So there are no competing nodes on the same block. And I believe transactions are being handled one at a time synchronously so you don't have to worry about any race conditions.

All 100 user will have a unique `gid` with this code.